# get_query_var not understanding my pages structure

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to s how pagination in my shortcode, all pages are showing up fine and clicking on relevant page takes to that page URL as well, but The page data never changes to that page, it always stays same and my portfolio posts are always same .... here is my whole code please any one help me out in figuring this problem.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
        );
        $push_args = array_slice($args, 0, 2, true) + $stack + $stack_cat_all + array_slice($args, 2, count($args) - 1, true) ;

        query_posts($push_args);
        if($show_title == 'yes'){
            $output = '<div class="section-title">';
            $output .= '<h3>'.$element_title.'</h3>';
            $output .= '<small>'.$element_caption.'</small>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        global $paged;
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {$paged = 1;}
        $args = array (
            'post_type' =>  'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        $gallery_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( !empty($gallery_posts) ) {
            if ($gallery_posts->have_posts()) {
                while ($gallery_posts->have_posts()) {
                    $gallery_posts->the_post();
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category');
                        $links = array();
                        if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)) {
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $links[] = $term->name;
                            }
                        }
                        $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links);
                        $tax = join(" ", $links);
                        $output .= '<div class="element-item ' . $tax . ' ' . $post_cols . '" data-category="transition">';
                        if ($thumbnail_position != 'below_title') {
                            if ($pretty_photo != 'no') {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '"></a>';
                            } else {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . $post->guid . '"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '"></a>';
                            }
                        }
                        if ($show_post_title != 'no') {
                            $output .= '<h3><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
                        }
                        if ($show_description != 'no') {
                            $output .= '<p>' . $content = substr(get_the_content(), 0, $num_characters) . '</p>';
                        }
                        if ($thumbnail_position == 'below_title') {
                            if ($pretty_photo != 'no') {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '"></a>';
                            } else {
                                $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)) . '"></a>';
                            }
                        }

                        if ($read_more != '') {
                            $read_more = $read_more;
                        } else {
                            $read_more = 'Read More';
                        }
                        if (($show_post_title != 'no') && ($show_description != 'no')) {
                            $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . $read_more . '</a>';
                        }
                        $output .= '</div>';
                }

                $output .= '</div>';

                //$output .= paginate_links( $args );
                if($show_pagination != 'no') {
                    $big = 999999999;
                    $output .= '<div class="portfolio-pagination">' . paginate_links(array(
                            'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                            'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
                            'total' => $gallery_posts->max_num_pages
                        ));
                    $output .= '</div>';
                }
                wp_reset_query();
                wp_reset_postdata();

                return $output;
            }
        }}
```

Its really killing me as wasted mine 3 hours by now :(

Comment: Your code looks fine at all, is this all your code or any thing extra also there ? If yes, then can you provide whole code that way it will be easy to find the issue ...

Comment: yes there is some other code, I am editing my question and providing that code as well ...

Comment: I have updated the code, new code is at top of previous code .... kindly guide me now ... please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is your wrong code, double query usage. Just comment this code

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
    );
    $push_args = array_slice($args, 0, 2, true) + $stack + $stack_cat_all + array_slice($args, 2, count($args) - 1, true) ;

    query_posts($push_args);
```

It is conflicting with your code and your $paged variable does not know what to do ?
Hope that solves issue ...